# Navigation menu can't hide/show (Responsive Design)

Tags: html, css

Here is the coding what I have provided this one. This is for responsive design. When I click the logo, it didn't want to hide or show.

```css
.toggle-nav {
  display: none;
}
.menu {
  float: right;
}
.menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: right;
}
.menuLink a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'alegreya_sansregular';
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menuLink a:hover,
.menu .current-item a {
  border-bottom: 4px double #FFF;
}
.fixedPosition {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .menu ul.active {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: -55px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #cecece;
  }
  .menu ul:after {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 87px;
    content: '';
    transform: translate(0%, -100%);
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #cecece;
  }
  .menu li {
    margin: 5px 0px;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .menuLink a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .menuLink a:hover,
  .menu .current-item a {
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #666;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #cecece;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: color linear 0.15s;
  }
  a.toggle-nav {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .toggle-nav:hover,
  .toggle-nav.active {
    color: #C3c3c3;
    border-bottom: none;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menuLink">
    <li> <a class="link-nav" data-scroll-nav="0"> HOME </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="works"> WORKS </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a data-scroll-nav="2"> ABOUT </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a data-scroll-nav="3"> CONTACT </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>
</nav>
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p2bg0kcy/).

Before I click, the menu is staying there and doesn't want to hide. What I want is the menu has to hide at first before I click the logo. And also the menu can hide back after click the logo when it's showing. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this jquery

```
$('.toggle-nav').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.menuLink').toggle();
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/p2bg0kcy/1/)

Comment: Thats really work. Anyway, how to hide the menu at first? I don't want the menu to show before I click the logo menu.

Comment: just set a display:none at the menu css. (.menuLink {display:none} )

Comment: No it doesn't work. The menu are still showing. I have tried to use `.menu {display:none;}` still doesn't work. Can you try this at your JSFiddle? Thanks.

Comment: `.menu ul {display:none;}` this one is working. Thanks by the way.

Comment: you can try to use slideToggle('slow') instead of toggle() to get a better effect on the menu open/close action. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example with expanding and animated menues.

https://jsfiddle.net/9bn5t0kj/8/

```js
$('.menu-header').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('menu-item-open');
    $('.menu-item').not($(this).next()).removeClass('menu-item-open');
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var clickedItem = $(e.target);
    
    if (clickedItem.is($('.menu-header')) || clickedItem.is($('.menu-item'))) {
        console.log(clickedItem);
        return;
    }
        
    $('.menu-item').removeClass('menu-item-open');
});
```

```css
.menu-item-container {
    float: left;
}

.menu-header {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-item {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height .25s;
}

.menu-item-open {
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item-container">
        <div class="menu-header">Open 1</div>
        <div class="menu-item">
            Hej hopp!<br>
            Hej hopp!<br>
            Hej hopp!<br>
            Hej hopp!<br>
            Hej hopp!<br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item-container">
        <div class="menu-header">Open 2</div>
        <div class="menu-item">
            Hej hopp 2!<br>
            Hej hopp 2!<br>
            Hej hopp 2!<br>
            Hej hopp 2!<br>
            Hej hopp 2!<br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it by default with `jQuery` `.hide()` and show it when `.toggle-nav` is clicked. it's pretty simple.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menuLink').hide();
  $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
    $('.menuLink').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle-nav {
  display: none;
}
.menu {
  float: right;
}
.menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: right;
}
.menuLink a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'alegreya_sansregular';
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menuLink a:hover,
.menu .current-item a {
  border-bottom: 4px double #FFF;
}
.fixedPosition {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .menu ul.active {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: -55px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #cecece;
  }
  .menu ul:after {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 87px;
    content: '';
    transform: translate(0%, -100%);
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #cecece;
  }
  .menu li {
    margin: 5px 0px;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .menuLink a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .menuLink a:hover,
  .menu .current-item a {
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #666;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #cecece;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: color linear 0.15s;
  }
  a.toggle-nav {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .toggle-nav:hover,
  .toggle-nav.active {
    color: #C3c3c3;
    border-bottom: none;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menuLink">
    <li> <a class="link-nav" data-scroll-nav="0"> HOME </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="works"> WORKS </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a data-scroll-nav="2"> ABOUT </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a data-scroll-nav="3"> CONTACT </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>
</nav>
```